# Moving column to the end of JSON in bash

Tags: json, bash, curl, awk, jq

I'm officially out of options, I tried everything.

I have a CSV that looks like this

| from/email | to/email | template_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| me@x.com | mike@x.com | 12345 |
| me@x.com | pete@x.com | 12345 |

I run a package called csvkit to convert CSV to JSON like this

`csvjson input.csv > output.json`

and pipe it into curl

`curl -X POST http://website.com -d @output.json`

and get a big fat error from the server saying "to/email is required"

I check my json in Sublime and it's fine

```
[
  {
    "from/email": "me@x.com",
    "to/0/email": "mike@x.com",
    "template_id": "12345"
  }
]
```

but I check my json with the terminal jtbl tool to visualize json

`cat output.json | jtbl`

and I get

| from/email | template_id | to/email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| me@x.com | 12345 | mike@x.com |
| me@x.com | 12345 | pete@x.com |

which makes no sense. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Is there a way to move my `template_id` column back to the end of the file instead of in the middle?

Comment: JSON objects have no ordering. The object has 3 properties, but nothing to tell which comes first. If you need ordering, use an array. It looks like jtbl is sorting by key name: does it have any options to tell it not to do that?

Comment: The JSON you show is valid but does not have a key named "to/email", just as the error message says.  It seems you might have two separate problems.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Q has the [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) tag, it might help to note that jq does (unless otherwise instructed) preserve the ordering of keys.  Apart from the headers, you could do worse than:

```
jq -r '(.[0]|keys_unsorted) as $keys | [.[][$keys[]]] | @csv' output.json
```